# How to include variables in custom filter function for dataframe?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, filter

I can't seem to get my R function to work which is designed to filter (dplyr) a data frame based on the filter value (character) and filter field input parameters. Here is my setup code:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),temp=c("a","b","c","d"))
 
filt_func <- function(input_df,filter_value,filter_field){
  filt_df <- input_df %>% dplyr::filter(grepl(filter_value,filter_field))
}
```

Now, when I run this without using a function it works?! Working code:

```
> df %>% dplyr::filter(grepl("d", temp))
  a temp
1 4    d
```

However, my function does not!

```
> output <- filt_func(df,"d",temp)
Error in `dplyr::filter()`:
i In argument: `grepl(filter_value, filter_field)`.
Caused by error in `is.factor()`:
! object 'temp' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Putting quotes around "temp" enables the code to run but the output is empty.

```
output <- filt_func(df,"d","temp")
```

I'm sure this is something silly but I've been starting at this too long and it's been a while since I coded functions. I tried adding `return(filt_df)` to the function but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to either `get` the string variable:

```
filt_func <- function(input_df,filter_value,filter_field){
  filt_df <- input_df %>% dplyr::filter(grepl(filter_value,get(filter_field)))
  filt_df
}

filt_func(df,"d","temp")
```

Or enclose it with `{{}}`:

```
filt_func <- function(input_df,filter_value,filter_field){
  filt_df <- input_df %>% dplyr::filter(grepl(filter_value,{{filter_field}}))
  filt_df
}

filt_func(df,"d",temp)
```

Both give:

```
  a temp
1 4    d
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommended methods for [programming with `dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) include `!!sym(.)` or `{{.}}` as benson23 already demonstrated).

```r
filt_func1 <- function(input_df, filter_value, filter_field) {
  input_df %>%
    dplyr::filter(grepl(filter_value, !!sym(filter_field)))
}
filt_func1(df, "d", "temp")
#   a temp
# 1 4    d
```

```r
filt_func2 <- function(input_df, filter_value, filter_field) {
  input_df %>%
    dplyr::filter(grepl(filter_value, {{ filter_field }}))
}
filt_func1(df, "d", "temp")
#   a temp
# 1 4    d
```

If you want to go NSE (non-standard evaluation), you can do this:

```r
filt_func3 <- function(input_df, filter_value, filter_field) {
  filter_field <- enquo(filter_field)
  input_df %>%
    dplyr::filter(grepl(filter_value, !!filter_field))
}
filt_func3(df, "d", temp)  # <-- notice that `temp` has no quotes, just the variable name
#   a temp
# 1 4    d
```

Comment: It's very comprehensive! But there's seems to be a typo in the code block of `filt_func2`, where you defined `filt_func2` but called `filt_func1`.

Comment: Thanks for seeing that @benson23. I would just edit it here but I want to make sure it was just a copy/paste mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to attain the same output by calling the dataframe column instead of calling a list

```
output <- filt_func(df,"d",df$temp)
```